# Bootstrap - Cannot change Navbar Title in CSS

Tags: html, css

**HTML- I want to change "One Million Lines" to white**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">One Million Lines</a>
        </div>
```

**Custom.CSS**
1. This is what I tried but it did not work
2. I have 2 css files in cascading order: bootstrapmin.css and custom.css
3. Code below is used to change color of "One Million Lines" in bootstrap.css
4. I want to use custom.css to change the color

```
.navbar-inverse .btn-link {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: welcome, Now accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep below line in custom.css file which should be loading after bootstrapmin.css file

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {color: white; }
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. You are a pro!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a more specific selector:

```
.navbar .container .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help